# Copy selection of numbers in a particular order into Excel

Tags: excel

In one part of my spreadsheet, I am calculating odds ratios.  I have one column (V) with the OR, and then W and X with the confidence intervals.  In another column (M), I am trying to get excel to list this information in one cell.
i.e.
0.78 (0.25, 2.46)
I have just been copying the information, but this is prone to errors and takes ages, so I am looking for a better way.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by _"I am trying to get excel to list this information in one cell..."_? Are you trying to have the OR and the confidence intervals displayed in col. M in the format above? i.e. '_OR_ (_CI1_, _CI2_)?

Comment: Yes, in one cell of one column - and then I hope to copy this down for all my other records (in a column)

Comment: Then @Danny Coveney's answer should work for you - that's pretty much what I would have suggested. So in M2 the formula should be `=V2&" ("&W2&", "&X2&")"`

Answer (score 1):

Try a formula like:

```
=[@columnV]&"("&[@columnW]&","&[@columnX]&")"
```

This should concatenate row wise down the entire table with the desired format.